# Manage Options not present in Add Attributes

Tags: attributes

Any idea why the option to add 'Manage Options' in Attributes does not exist in the new attribute I have added?

[image]

Comment: Add Option will be only with `Dropdown` and `Multiselect` options of `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` are you sure you choose any of these types??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic due to inactivity from OP.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the attribute input type was not set to `Dropdown` or `Multiselect`.